# How to get number of items in array which have the same "parent" element?

Tags: javascript

I gave an array of items which looks like this

```
const array = [{
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 1',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    type: 'item',
    name: 'item 1',
    data: {
      section: {
        name: 'name 1',
        id: '1'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'item',
    name: 'item 2',
    data: {
      section: {
        id: '1',
        name: 'name 1'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 2',
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    type: 'item',
    name: 'item 1',
    data: {
      section: {
        id: '3',
        name: 'name 2'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 3'
  }, {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 4'
  },
]
```

I need to count and add to each object of type `section` the number of `items` that it has `(numberOfItems: 3)`. The array is built that way that each section has its items follow it.
I also have a separate array of items which basically looks like that

```
const items = [{
  'item_id: {
  ...
  section: {
    id: 'section_id'
    name: 'section_name'
  }
}]
```

I'm not really sure how to even start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your problem correctly then this code should do it:

```
const array = [
  {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 1',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    type: 'item',
    name: 'item 1',
    data: {
      section: {
        name: 'name 1',
        id: '1'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'item',
    name: 'item 2',
    data: {
      section: {
        id: '1',
        name: 'name 1'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 2',
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    type: 'item',
    name: 'item 1',
    data: {
      section: {
        id: '3',
        name: 'name 2'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 3'
  }, {
    type: 'section',
    name: 'name 4'
  },
];

let section;
for (let item of array) {
    console.log(item);
  if (item.type === "section") {
    section = item;
    section.numberOfItems = 0;
  } else if (item.type === "item" && section) {
    section.numberOfItems++;
  }
}
```

It steps through all elements, keeps a record when it finds a section and increments the count of the previously found section when it finds an item.